# How to add close caption in the MediaFront module?

Tags: 7

I have the [MediaFront](https://www.drupal.org/project/mediafront) module installed in my site. Thats uses OSM player to play.

I need a close caption button in OSM player.

How can I do this?

Comment: Looks like there's no support for it: https://www.drupal.org/node/2273333. The module developer estimated 50 hours work to implement it, so it's probably not something that an answer here is going to be able to cover